# How to add Object to the array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to add the Object to the array of object.

My array is in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5w4zhw92/

The Expected

```
var sensors = [
{ id: 'led', name: 'LED', type: { port: '', path: '' } },
{ id: 'temp', name: 'TEMP', type: { path: '' } },
];
```

Comment: define `sensorType` before it is used

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5w4zhw92/2/

Answer (score 1):

It's already working you just need to declare the variable before using it.Declare `sensorType` first then use it.

```
var sensorType = {
    sender: {
        port: '',
        path: ''
    },
    receiver: {
        path: ''
    }
    };
var sensors = [
    { id: 'led', name: 'LED', type: sensorType.sender },
    { id: 'temp', name: 'TEMP', type: sensorType.receiver }
    ];

    console.log(sensorType.sender);
    console.log(sensors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change order of statements in your code. Declare sensorType object first.

```js
var sensorType = {
        sender: {
            port: '',
            path: ''
        },
        receiver: {
            path: ''
        }
    };

    var sensors = [
    { id: 'led', name: 'LED', type: sensorType.sender },
    { id: 'temp', name: 'TEMP', type: sensorType.receiver },
    ];

    console.log(sensorType.sender); //Returns Object {port: "", path: ""}
    console.log(sensors); //[{ id: 'led', name: 'LED', type: { port: '', path: '' } },{ id: 'temp', name: 'TEMP', type: { path: '' } }];
```